# Include plus or minus in sum program

Tags: java, sum, addition, subtraction

This is a program that asks for user input (number) and prints a sum statement. Which continually works until user enters END. It works fine, however when a negative integer is inputted, an empty print statement is returned. Any help or insight into how to include negative integers in the sum is greatly appreciated thanks for your time!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int sum = 0; 
    String val = "";
while (val.equals("")) 
{
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    val = scan.nextLine();
if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {   
    break;      
}
else if (val.matches("\\d+")) {   
    sum += Integer.parseInt(val);
    System.out.println("Sum is now: " + sum);   
}
else {
    System.err.println("");
}
val = "";  
}   
}
}
```

Comment: You need to add an (optional) minus sign to your regex: `-?\\d+`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Sum of numbers until string is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61413651/java-sum-of-numbers-until-string-is-entered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be because `\\d+` picks up one or more numbers. Whereas the `-` before a negative number is not considered a number so therefore it does not match your regex.

Try using something like:

`-?\\d+`

Comment: Why include decimals when the OP clearly uses types?